# Изменить высоту trumbnail и выровнять содержимое

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Для выравнивания высоты `trumbnail` и содержимого в нем реализован следующий скрипт:

```
function adjustThumbnailHeight() {
var heights = []
var infoblock = []

jQuery('.thumbnail').each(function() {
    heights.push( jQuery(this).height() )
})

jQuery('.can_resize').each(function() {
    infoblock.push( jQuery(this).height() )
})

var infoblockOne = infoblock.splice(0, 2)
var infoblockTwo = infoblock

var heightsOne = heights.splice(0, 2)
var heightsTwo = heights

var maxOne = Math.max.apply(null, heightsOne)
var maxTwo = Math.max.apply(null, heightsTwo)

var maxInfoOne = Math.max.apply(null, infoblockOne)
var maxInfoTwo = Math.max.apply(null, infoblockTwo)

jQuery('.thumbnail:eq('+  0 + ')').height(maxOne)
jQuery('.thumbnail:eq('+  1 + ')').height(maxOne)
jQuery('.thumbnail:eq('+  2 + ')').height(maxTwo)
jQuery('.thumbnail:eq('+  3 + ')').height(maxTwo)
jQuery('.thumbnail:eq('+  4 + ')').height(maxTwo)

jQuery('.can_resize:eq('+  0 + ')').height(maxInfoOne)
jQuery('.can_resize:eq('+  1 + ')').height(maxInfoOne)
jQuery('.can_resize:eq('+  2 + ')').height(maxInfoTwo)
jQuery('.can_resize:eq('+  3 + ')').height(maxInfoTwo)
jQuery('.can_resize:eq('+  4 + ')').height(maxInfoTwo)

 }

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.thumbnail').imagesLoaded( function() {

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        adjustThumbnailHeight()
    })
    jQuery(document).ready(adjustThumbnailHeight())
})

})
```

На рисунке 1 изображено как должно быть (оно так и есть при загрузке). 
[image: рисунок 1]

При изменении размеров окна 'плывет' класс `can_resize` (см. рисунок 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подскажет, как в таких случаях правильно реализовать алгоритм фиксирования размеров класса `trumbnail` с изменением положения текста. Может поможет отрефакторить существующий алгоритм. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы выставляете высоту своим элементам, она прописывается в style каждому элемемнту. После изменения размера окна jquery считывает высоту из стиля, которую вы задали в прошлый раз и заново выставляет ее же. По этой причине ничего не изменяется.

Заметка: если вы используете bootstrap, то размер сетки изменяется лишь при изменении размера окна между специфичными значениями (посмотрите [раздел grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)), поэтому для экономии времени на вычислениях можно выполнять скрипт только при реальном изменении ширины контейнера.